# PXDefault Null reference on field added in OrderType

Tags: c#, customization, acumatica

I've already added a new field `UsrUserRole` on OrderType for screen SO201000 :

```
 [PXDBString(64)]
 [PXDefault(PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
 [PXSelector(typeof(Search<PX.SM.Roles.rolename>))]
 [PXUIField(DisplayName="User Role", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
```

I get the error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

when it's null. So how can I set the default value selector order type ? Here is the `SOOrder` customization I have done for `OrderType`

```
[PXDefault(typeof(Search2<SOOrderType.orderType,
                    InnerJoin<PX.SM.UsersInRoles, 
                        On<PX.SM.UsersInRoles.rolename, 
                            Equal<SOOrderTypeExt.usrUserRole>>>,
                    Where<PX.SM.UsersInRoles.username, 
                        Equal<Current<AccessInfo.userName>>>>), 
                        PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
[PXSelector(typeof(Search5<SOOrderType.orderType,
        InnerJoin<SOOrderTypeOperation, 
            On<SOOrderTypeOperation.orderType, 
                Equal<SOOrderType.orderType>, 
            And<SOOrderTypeOperation.operation, 
                Equal<SOOrderType.defaultOperation>>>,
        LeftJoin<SOSetupApproval, 
            On<SOOrderType.orderType, 
                Equal<SOSetupApproval.orderType>>,
        InnerJoin<PX.SM.UsersInRoles, 
            On<PX.SM.UsersInRoles.rolename, 
                Equal<SOOrderTypeExt.usrUserRole>>>>>,
        Aggregate<GroupBy<SOOrderType.orderType>>>),DescriptionField = typeof(SOOrderTypeT.descr))]
[PXRestrictor(typeof(Where<PX.SM.UsersInRoles.username, 
                        Equal<Current<AccessInfo.userName>>>), null)]
```

Comment: Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to improve chances of receiving an answer !

Comment: @SimonML, thanks so much.

Comment: Could you give us the full code snippets of `UsrUserRole` and `OrderType`. When exactly do you get the null reference exception, what are you doing when you get it ? Please also provide the software version number

Comment: @SimonML, I've already added the new field UsruserRole on Order Type screen as the coding above and in Order Type existed field on SOOrder screen I customized the coding as above also. After then I assign the role name as Admin for ordertype="C1" but when the first time I didn't assign the role it got error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would expect one of properties, like IsCreditMemoOrder or IsTransferOrder, declared within SOOrderEntry to throw the "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error.

The current design of the Sales Orders screen always expects current user to have access to at least one Order Type, which your SOOrder customization doesn't completely follow.

The possible solution will be to override attributes of the SOOrder SalesOrder field as follows:

```
[PXDBString(2, IsKey = true, IsFixed = true, InputMask=">aa")]
[PXDefault(SOOrderTypeConstants.SalesOrder, typeof(SOSetup.defaultOrderType))]
[PXSelector(typeof(Search5<SOOrderType.orderType,
        InnerJoin<SOOrderTypeOperation, 
            On<SOOrderTypeOperation.orderType, 
                Equal<SOOrderType.orderType>, 
            And<SOOrderTypeOperation.operation, 
                Equal<SOOrderType.defaultOperation>>>,
        LeftJoin<SOSetupApproval, 
            On<SOOrderType.orderType, 
                Equal<SOSetupApproval.orderType>>,
        InnerJoin<PX.SM.UsersInRoles, 
            On<PX.SM.UsersInRoles.rolename, 
                Equal<SOOrderTypeExt.usrUserRole>>>>>,
        Aggregate<GroupBy<SOOrderType.orderType>>>),DescriptionField = typeof(SOOrderTypeT.descr))]
[PXRestrictor(typeof(Where<PX.SM.UsersInRoles.username, 
                        Equal<Current<AccessInfo.userName>>>), "Access not granted")]
[PXRestrictor(typeof(Where<SOOrderTypeOperation.iNDocType, NotEqual<INTranType.transfer>, Or<FeatureInstalled<FeaturesSet.warehouse>>>), ErrorMessages.ElementDoesntExist, typeof(SOOrderType.orderType))]
[PXRestrictor(typeof(Where<SOOrderType.requireAllocation, NotEqual<True>, Or<AllocationAllowed>>), ErrorMessages.ElementDoesntExist, typeof(SOOrderType.orderType))]
[PXRestrictor(typeof(Where<SOOrderType.active,Equal<True>>), null)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Order Type", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
[PX.Data.EP.PXFieldDescription]
```

And accomplish that with the following SOOrderEntry extension:

```
public class SOOrderEntryExt : PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry>
{
    public void SOOrder_OrderType_FieldDefaulting(PXCache sender, PXFieldDefaultingEventArgs e)
    {
        var query = new PXSelectJoin<SOOrderType,
                InnerJoin<PX.SM.UsersInRoles,
                    On<PX.SM.UsersInRoles.rolename,
                        Equal<SOOrderTypeExt.usrUserRole>>>,
                Where<PX.SM.UsersInRoles.username,
                    Equal<Current<AccessInfo.userName>>>>(Base);
        var orderType = query.SelectSingle();
        if (orderType != null)
        {
            e.NewValue = orderType.OrderType;
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }

    public void SOOrder_RowSelected(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        SOOrder order = e.Row as SOOrder;

        bool disabled = Base.soordertype.Current == null;
        if (!disabled)
        {
            string userRole = Base.soordertype.Current.GetExtension<SOOrderTypeExt>().UsrUserRole;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userRole) || !PXContext.PXIdentity.User.IsInRole(userRole))
            {
                disabled = true;
            }
        }

        if (disabled)
        {
            SetReadOnly(true);
            sender.AllowInsert = true;
            sender.RaiseExceptionHandling<SOOrder.orderType>(order, order.OrderType, 
                new PXSetPropertyException("Access not granted for current user", PXErrorLevel.Warning));
        }
    }

    protected void SetReadOnly(bool isReadOnly)
    {
        foreach (PXCache cache in Base.Caches.Values)
        {
            cache.AllowDelete = !isReadOnly;
            cache.AllowUpdate = !isReadOnly;
            cache.AllowInsert = !isReadOnly;
        }
    }
}
```

BLC extension will make sure to first default Order Type based on your custom User Role field. If User Role is empty for an order type, the system will use SOSetup.defaultOrderType, as set up in original declaration of the PXDefaultAttibute. If current user is not part of the role specified for an order type, user will receive the "Access not granted for current user" warning and won't be able to create, modify or delete any order of selected type.

Comment: It got error: "A column has been specified more than once in the order by list. Column in the order by list must be unique." on screen Order Type: ScreenId=SO201000.

Comment: Try restarting IIS, there might be an issue with field attributes